# Nextjs dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my nextjs app I have profile pages. I want the routing to be like this:

```
/@username
```

That's why I have used this file format:

```
@[username].js
```

But this is not working. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add it under a page something like this:

```
pages/user/[username].js
```

Any route like `/user/@john`, `/user/@mark`, etc. will be matched by `pages/user/[username].js`. The matched path parameter will be sent as a query parameter to the page.

You'll have access to the `query` object as

```
{ "username": "@john" }
```

**[username].js**

```
export default function User(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Username: {props.url.query.username} </h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

eg: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-goldwasser-cc2nb)

Hope this helps !